# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info'

Tags: python, attributeerror

This is under Anime.py file

```
     import requests
     import json
     import random
     from funcy import join

     def anime():
      def __init__(self):
         self.url = f'https://animechan.vercel.app/api/quotes/character?name=saitama'
   

      def get_info(self):
       r = requests.get(self.url)
    
       response = r.json()
    
       join(response)
    
       values_of_key = [a_dict["quote"] for a_dict in response]
       return values_of_key
```

I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_info' error when I call this in main()

```
  import requests
  import Anime
  from Anime import anime

  def main():
   results = Anime.anime()
   results.get_info()
   print(results.get_info)


  main()
```

Comment: You need to show the `main` function you are mentionning, otherwise there is no way to help.

Comment: Is anime supposed to be a class...

Comment: You need to fix the indentations on your code.  and the part that threw the error isn't even included in your code.  Please include the full error traceback

Comment: I included main now!

Answer (score 0):

Youre attempting to use a class, but defining it as a function which returns nothing.

Your code should look as below.

```
class anime():
  def __init__(self):
     self.url = f'https://animechan.vercel.app/api/quotes/character?name=saitama'


  def get_info(self):
   r = requests.get(self.url)

   response = r.json()

   join(response)

   values_of_key = [a_dict["quote"] for a_dict in response]
   return values_of_key
```

Comment: dear god how did i miss that